# How to update existing Paypal account in Braintree?

Tags: paypal, braintree, braintree-data

I want to update existing `paypalAccount` of a Vault user every time she makes a purchase using paypal checkout.

According to the [documentation](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method/update/node#payment_method_nonce), I can only update `creditCards` using `paymentMethodNonce`.

Another piece of [documentation](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method/update/node#updating-a-paypal-account-token) shows how to update Paypal account using `token`. My understanding is that `token` is only available only after `paymentMethod` is added to Vault.

But all I know at this point (before I update the Vault) is `paymentMethodNonce` from the client-side. And I don't want to create a new `paymentMethod`/`paypalAccount` but to update the existing one.

Is there any way that I can update existing `paypalAccount` using `paymentMethodNonce`?

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Currently there is not a way to update a paypalAccount using a paymentMethodNonce.

You can update a paypalAccount by updating the paymentMethod tied to the paypalAccount. First, save a mapping from user to a payment_method_token on your server. The [payment_method_token](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/payment-method/node#token) will be returned from [`paymentMethod.create`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method/create/node). Then, anytime you want to update a user's details, you can retrieve the paymentMethod using the token, and call [`paymentMethod.update`](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method/update/node).

For more information on updating paypalAccounts, please check out this [documentation](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/payment-method/update/node#updating-a-paypal-account-token).

Comment: Thanks for answering the question! I wanted to map users in my server only to their braintree `customerId` because I can update the new user info + new credit card info in one call using `paymentMethodNonce`, but if mapping `paymentMethodToken` to `customer` is the only way to update the `paypalAccount`, I will follow your advice.